# Result strange to use function file_get_contents()

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the contents of the URL by using the tool
file_get_contents('http://player.vimeo.com/external/155119694.sd.mp4?s=56e2df64c6b098a7c9a7402c7f6179201e44a029&profile_id=112&oauth2_token_id=407699588');
But the result is very strange, someone can tell me why this result?

ftypmp42mp42mp41isomavc1›moovlmvhdÒã–[Òã–[X!Y@*iods€€€Oÿÿ)ÿ€€€€€€`trak\tkhdÒã–[Òã–[!*@€h$edtselst!*Ømdia mdhdÒã–[Òã–[UÄ6hdlrvideL-SMASH Video Handlerzminfvmhd$dinfdrefurl :stblÃstsd³avc1€hHH AVC Codingÿÿ:avcCdÿágd¬Ù@ /ùp À ¨@xÁŒ°hëì²,ýøøcolrnclxpaspsttsèctts$stss=yµñ'sdtp¦––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––š¦––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––š¦––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––š¦––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––š¦––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš––šš–š(stsc €stszÿ€ ÈüFB›w‚“c` ÑEÓ><�Ò!I90E ÿC+Ì%X<�*1CF½D>[/)æç#Ö'4 mAM oX5g" {pU‚°¾<� ¬I’j{q1)4 ê$ê')6'%üO)P0,   jDÌX„kˆ“£CëqH,FT$¢:3jÿ`’%)õc2-óƒ>?J=×`Ÿ|   0å‡[ïqH# bOžk/¶e1°RÙN+Q=)!(ßN+!*-+UcT-9O4õgHU<�)!`;HstcoËð’VÅì 5Éº‹¦ØÄ³"    *¥  §T |nòÀþsgpdrollsbgprolltrak\tkhdÒã–[Òã–[!Y@$edtselst!Ymdia mdhdÒã–[Òã–[»€ lUÄ6hdlrsounL-SMASH Audio Handler·minfsmhd$dinfdrefurl {stblgstsdWmp4a»€3esds€€€"€€€@«¯0€€€€€€stts›(stsc/     €stsz›‚«qsjW9.+0!%&",ûûþ   3$? -!-)üîðûúõ      ,TCýÿ þ&6   „%;ýÿ   9þK     D I‡    ù øþ    ,*ÿ?Œ  b%þþ yù÷ý   JD.ô-ö(óýûþ    OF    ÿþK úü    &  # Q $û 1 >D }1ûúù ÿþ   -M! 9(þ         I   !  -o   ú        0JLø           "    #  &RE?û y<�øùÿ'&öüKLÿþþûù  ˆ  N ÿ *#T;ýüþ ;rùþ h úù&0E0K  ü1  ü 16  ûLstco‰D¾$“¹œwçzXõ¦—€¡ø^  tñ  Ò<&4í'free×mdatÿÿÿÜEé½æÙH·–,Ø Ù#îïx264 - core 148 r11 a01e339 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=11 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 stitchable=1 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=infinite keyint_min=20 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=2pass mbtree=1 bitrate=750 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=5 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 cplxblur=20.0 qblur=0.5 vbv_maxrate=825 vbv_bufsize=900 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00€üYeˆ„ÿþÇóøº•'ëâSÐ,)}; €!ÓŽa–™¾zŽOYJ4©LŽ°;oËãf·Ìpó[A   ÔÊ4jé%•;ÉZa\Ò/  $6+ä«4fLyiƒ×«gc¹Í)þåµ*ŠV-@‹ý‘M›²2“F‚øy³6¹Â!ó6Ïû1••Ú:lŸ'#Šˆ¨ý7ðýSˆ2¢¼€žbvRKO¼îª¸û•'àË1¸lL°t‘ÂQ©†eå7ºòƒè¾ÃJALn?ŠÝÜ*Npc!³iñ2¥r6»äP©6àv~4f7ï0s)ãÆ

Comment: You are downloading an MP4 file. This is a possible content for an MP4 video file. What are you trying to do? Do you want to store the video locally?

Comment: <video controls  id="url" src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/155119694.sd.mp4?s=56e2df64c6b098a7c9a7402c7f6179201e44a029&profile_id=112&oauth2_token_id=407699588"> </video> I need to get the source URL of the video because this URL that is within the SRC = "" is just a redirect to the URL source of the video, but I'm unable to get the source URL of the video after the redirect without leaving the page.

Answer (score 2):

The URL you are talking of:

`http://player.vimeo.com/external/155119694.sd.mp4?s=56e2df64c6b098a7c9a7402c7f6179201e44a029&profile_id=112&oauth2_token_id=407699588`

...is - in this case - redirected to a different URL (you can easily verify it by a browser):

`https://fpdl.vimeocdn.com/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/1023/6/155119694/480188332.mp4?token=56bf93f0_0x229f060ec6a77cfd556b0e21fec1171b822cd30c`

When you want to store it locally to your client workstation your code could look like this:

### Code

```
<?php

    $url_original = 'http://player.vimeo.com/external/155119694.sd.mp4?s=56e2df64c6b098a7c9a7402c7f6179201e44a029&profile_id=112&oauth2_token_id=407699588';
    $url_redirected = '';

    // Get redirection
    $headers = get_headers($url_original,1);
    $url_redirected = $headers['Location'][1];
    echo "<p>Original URL = <br />$url_original </p>";
    echo "<p>Redirected URL from \$headers['Location'][1] = <br />$url_redirected </p>";
    // echo 'All the headers:<pre>'; print_r($headers); echo '</pre>';

    // Get the file from the original server
    $video = file_get_contents($url_redirected);

    // Store the file to local server
    // $filename = '/downloaded_video.mp4';
    $filename = dirname(__FILE__) . '/downloaded_video.mp4';
    file_put_contents($filename , $video); 

    // Download to the client workstation
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=downloaded_video.mp4');
    header('Content-type: video/mp4');
    echo $video;

?>
```

### Notes

- This code has not been tested though.
- The redirection adds a token that changes every time the request is made.
  This token probably will time out, and when it is timed out the request with the original URL must be repeated to get a redirection URL with a valid token. You can call this "hacker prevention".
- You have now a set of manipulations with this URL - hopefully to learn from!

Comment: I need to get the URL without running directly in the browser: https://fpdl.vimeocdn.com/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/1023/6/155119694/480188332.mp4?token=56bf93f0_0x229f060ec6a77cfd556b0e21fec1171b822cd30c

Comment: You're really not doing yourself any favours leaving answers on such bad questions.

Comment: To find out what the redirected URL is you can use the **get_headers** function. Then look for the **Location** array. This array contains 2 entries: the original and the redirection URL.

Comment: Thank you!! I could solve the problem by using get_headers ()